# VBA MonthView Userform Control Read in Multi Select

Tags: vba

This is the first time I've used MonthView in a userform and am able to read the selection into a string with a simple MonthView.Value. However, I need to be able to read in a multiselect and am totally stumped on how to cycle through the dates to find both of the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SelStart and SelEnd properties of the monthview control.